# jCarouselLite - Forcing List Items onto Single Line

Tags: jquery, jcarousel, jcarousellite

I am using jCarousellite on a list on a website I am building.  It works perfectly, however the issue is that for some reason, the script is causing List Items to stop stacking.

What I mean by this is - instead of this:

```
li     li
li     li
```

I am getting this:

```
li     li     li      li
```

It works fine when I remove the script, but with it, its forcing them all onto a single "line".  I've looked through the script and cannot figure out what part is forcing them all onto a single line.

Here is the script: http://www.trekradio.net/dev/wp-content/themes/tr2012/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js

You can also see a demo of the problem here in the "Whats On" Section of the Heaer: http://www.trekradio.net/dev/  (this site is under construction so forgive its state).

EDIT:  Setting the "vertical" option to "true" in the script changes the carousel scrolling to vertical AND displays the list items like this, which is not what I want:

```
li

li

li

li
```

Comment: I would imaging this is to do with the plugin making the `li` elements `float`, instead of `block` or `inline-block`

Comment: They need to be floated.  Without the script, I have them floated left and they display as I want.  I tried adding "display:block" and "display:inline-block" but it didn't make a diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED : [ugly fix]**

here is the line you need to update in `jcarousellite_1.0.1.js` (you add the tiny `/ 2`  bit) :

```
    var ulSize = liSize * itemLength / 2;                   // size of full ul(total length, not just for the visible items)
```

Beware since it will impact all other Carousels in any other page.

**UPDATE 2 : backward compatible fix**

I patched the .js file, and you can use option `lines` in your code, or leave it with 1 line by default :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".anyClass").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev",
        lines : 2
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is [the patched `jcarousellite_1.0.1.js`](http://paste.org/49668)

Good luck !

--

I am afraid that this would bend jCarouselLite a little too far.

I would advise you to split the `li` in two `ul`, by PHP or even by manipulating the DOM in Javascript/jquery.

This way, you can achieve your goal by setting up two parallel horizontal carousels running together.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thats fantastic :)  Thank you for looking at this :)

Comment: @ZachNicodemous : you are welcome, I learnt something too ! bounties do work sometimes :)